# Colorbox and Dynamic Inline HTML

Tags: html, dynamic, inline, colorbox

I've got a form in .NET.
when the user presses submit, a sub is launched to check all checkboxes, radiobuttons, etc...
and when there's an issue, i'm adding the specific issue to a stringbuilder

as per below

```
Dim errors As New StringBuilder
If APACradio.Checked = False And EMEAradio.Checked = False And LATAMCANADAradio.Checked = False Then
        errors.AppendLine(" You must select a Region")
    End If

    If CountryDDL.SelectedValue = "Select" Then
        errors.AppendLine(" You must select a Country")
    End If

    If EmploymentDDL.SelectedValue = "Select" Then
        errors.AppendLine(" You must select a Employment Type")
    End If

etc....
```

At the end of the check, i would like a Colorbox to appear, listing the lines of the stringbuilder, one by one.

I've worked with colorbox's inline HRef's before and i love that but this is a bit different as i can not preload my document with the  code here.
Colorbox page itself shows samples on how to load a HTML page (sample 5) but my HTML i want to show would be rather in memory than on a disk somewhere

Answer (score 4):

Why not use ColorBox's html property?  Example:

```
$.colorbox({html:function(){
  var html = '';
  // do your formatting
  return html;
}});
```

Comment: good point, i guess i was thinking too complex here. I've solved it in the meantime using placeholders, literalcontrols and a clientstartupscript . (I'm not so good in javascripting )